# can I use the pre trained model with different input channel size?

Tags: model, pytorch, resnet

The pretrained model accepts the input shape like this;

```
[batch_Size, Channels, Depth, Height, Width]
[32, 3, 16, 224,224]
```

I want to give it;

```
[batch_Size, Channels, Depth, Height, Width]
[32, 2, 16, 224,224]
```

It is giving me this error;

[image]

It is saying that the weight of pretrained model of first layer is [16,3,1,3,3], it expecting to have 3 channels but it got 2 channels instead. I have also kept strict = False in state_dict_load, but still giving me this error, should I have to go through each weight and change the reduce the channel? or should I train it from scratch?

Here is the pretrained model layers and their output;

```
conv1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([16, 3, 1, 3, 3])
conv1.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([16])
conv1.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([16])
blocks.b0_l0.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b0_l0.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 16, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l0.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b0_l0.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b0_l0.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 1, 1, 5, 5])
blocks.b0_l0.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b0_l0.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b0_l0.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([16, 40, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l0.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([16])
blocks.b0_l0.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 16, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l0.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b0_l0.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([16, 40, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l0.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([16])
blocks.b0_l0.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([16])
blocks.b0_l0.res.1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([16, 16, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l0.res.1.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([16])
blocks.b0_l0.res.1.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([16])
blocks.b0_l1.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b0_l1.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 16, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l1.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b0_l1.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b0_l1.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b0_l1.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b0_l1.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b0_l1.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([16, 40, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l1.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([16])
blocks.b0_l1.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 16, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l1.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b0_l1.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([16, 40, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l1.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([16])
blocks.b0_l1.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([16])
blocks.b0_l2.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b0_l2.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([64, 16, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l2.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b0_l2.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b0_l2.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([64, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b0_l2.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b0_l2.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b0_l2.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([16, 64, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l2.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([16])
blocks.b0_l2.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([64, 16, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l2.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b0_l2.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([16, 64, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b0_l2.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([16])
blocks.b0_l2.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([16])
blocks.b1_l0.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b1_l0.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([96, 16, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l0.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l0.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l0.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([96, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b1_l0.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l0.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l0.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([24, 96, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l0.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([24])
blocks.b1_l0.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([96, 24, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l0.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l0.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 96, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l0.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b1_l0.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b1_l0.res.1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 16, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l0.res.1.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b1_l0.res.1.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b1_l1.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b1_l1.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([120, 40, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l1.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b1_l1.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b1_l1.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([120, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b1_l1.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b1_l1.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b1_l1.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([32, 120, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l1.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([32])
blocks.b1_l1.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([120, 32, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l1.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b1_l1.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 120, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l1.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b1_l1.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b1_l2.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b1_l2.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([96, 40, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l2.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l2.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l2.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([96, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b1_l2.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l2.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l2.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([24, 96, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l2.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([24])
blocks.b1_l2.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([96, 24, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l2.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l2.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 96, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l2.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b1_l2.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b1_l3.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b1_l3.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([96, 40, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l3.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l3.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l3.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([96, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b1_l3.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l3.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l3.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([24, 96, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l3.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([24])
blocks.b1_l3.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([96, 24, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l3.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b1_l3.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 96, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l3.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b1_l3.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b1_l4.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b1_l4.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([120, 40, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l4.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b1_l4.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b1_l4.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([120, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b1_l4.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b1_l4.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b1_l4.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([32, 120, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l4.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([32])
blocks.b1_l4.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([120, 32, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l4.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b1_l4.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 120, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b1_l4.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b1_l4.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b2_l0.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b2_l0.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 40, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l0.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l0.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l0.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 1, 5, 3, 3])
blocks.b2_l0.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l0.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l0.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([64, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l0.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b2_l0.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 64, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l0.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l0.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([72, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l0.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b2_l0.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b2_l0.res.1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([72, 40, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l0.res.1.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b2_l0.res.1.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b2_l1.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b2_l1.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([160, 72, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l1.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([160])
blocks.b2_l1.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([160])
blocks.b2_l1.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([160, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b2_l1.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([160])
blocks.b2_l1.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([160])
blocks.b2_l1.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 160, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l1.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b2_l1.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([160, 40, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l1.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([160])
blocks.b2_l1.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([72, 160, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l1.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b2_l1.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b2_l2.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b2_l2.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 72, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l2.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l2.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l2.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b2_l2.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l2.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l2.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([64, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l2.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b2_l2.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 64, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l2.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l2.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([72, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l2.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b2_l2.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b2_l3.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b2_l3.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([192, 72, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l3.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([192])
blocks.b2_l3.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([192])
blocks.b2_l3.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([192, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b2_l3.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([192])
blocks.b2_l3.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([192])
blocks.b2_l3.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([48, 192, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l3.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([48])
blocks.b2_l3.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([192, 48, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l3.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([192])
blocks.b2_l3.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([72, 192, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l3.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b2_l3.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b2_l4.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b2_l4.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 72, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l4.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l4.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l4.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b2_l4.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l4.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l4.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([64, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l4.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b2_l4.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 64, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l4.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b2_l4.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([72, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b2_l4.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b2_l4.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b3_l0.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b3_l0.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 72, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l0.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l0.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l0.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 1, 5, 3, 3])
blocks.b3_l0.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l0.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l0.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([64, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l0.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b3_l0.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 64, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l0.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l0.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([72, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l0.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b3_l0.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b3_l1.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b3_l1.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 72, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l1.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l1.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l1.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b3_l1.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l1.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l1.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([64, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l1.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b3_l1.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 64, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l1.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l1.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([72, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l1.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b3_l1.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b3_l2.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b3_l2.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 72, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l2.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l2.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l2.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b3_l2.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l2.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l2.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([64, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l2.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b3_l2.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 64, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l2.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l2.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([72, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l2.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b3_l2.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b3_l3.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b3_l3.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 72, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l3.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l3.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l3.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b3_l3.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l3.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l3.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([64, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l3.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b3_l3.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 64, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l3.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l3.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([72, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l3.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b3_l3.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b3_l4.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b3_l4.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([144, 72, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l4.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b3_l4.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b3_l4.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([144, 1, 1, 5, 5])
blocks.b3_l4.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b3_l4.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b3_l4.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([40, 144, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l4.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([40])
blocks.b3_l4.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([144, 40, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l4.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b3_l4.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([72, 144, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l4.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b3_l4.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b3_l5.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b3_l5.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 72, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l5.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l5.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l5.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b3_l5.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l5.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l5.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([64, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l5.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([64])
blocks.b3_l5.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([240, 64, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l5.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([240])
blocks.b3_l5.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([72, 240, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b3_l5.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b3_l5.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([72])
blocks.b4_l0.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b4_l0.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([480, 72, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l0.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l0.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l0.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([480, 1, 5, 3, 3])
blocks.b4_l0.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l0.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l0.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([120, 480, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l0.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b4_l0.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([480, 120, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l0.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l0.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([144, 480, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l0.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l0.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l0.res.1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([144, 72, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l0.res.1.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l0.res.1.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l1.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b4_l1.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([384, 144, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l1.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([384])
blocks.b4_l1.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([384])
blocks.b4_l1.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([384, 1, 1, 5, 5])
blocks.b4_l1.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([384])
blocks.b4_l1.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([384])
blocks.b4_l1.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([96, 384, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l1.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b4_l1.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([384, 96, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l1.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([384])
blocks.b4_l1.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([144, 384, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l1.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l1.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l2.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b4_l2.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([384, 144, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l2.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([384])
blocks.b4_l2.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([384])
blocks.b4_l2.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([384, 1, 1, 5, 5])
blocks.b4_l2.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([384])
blocks.b4_l2.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([384])
blocks.b4_l2.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([96, 384, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l2.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([96])
blocks.b4_l2.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([384, 96, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l2.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([384])
blocks.b4_l2.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([144, 384, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l2.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l2.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l3.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b4_l3.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([480, 144, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l3.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l3.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l3.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([480, 1, 1, 5, 5])
blocks.b4_l3.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l3.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l3.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([120, 480, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l3.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b4_l3.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([480, 120, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l3.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l3.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([144, 480, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l3.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l3.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l4.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b4_l4.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([480, 144, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l4.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l4.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l4.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([480, 1, 1, 5, 5])
blocks.b4_l4.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l4.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l4.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([120, 480, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l4.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b4_l4.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([480, 120, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l4.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l4.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([144, 480, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l4.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l4.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l5.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b4_l5.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([480, 144, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l5.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l5.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l5.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([480, 1, 3, 3, 3])
blocks.b4_l5.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l5.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l5.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([120, 480, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l5.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([120])
blocks.b4_l5.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([480, 120, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l5.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([480])
blocks.b4_l5.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([144, 480, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l5.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l5.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l6.alpha : torch.Size([])
blocks.b4_l6.expand.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([576, 144, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l6.expand.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([576])
blocks.b4_l6.expand.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([576])
blocks.b4_l6.deep.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([576, 1, 1, 3, 3])
blocks.b4_l6.deep.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([576])
blocks.b4_l6.deep.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([576])
blocks.b4_l6.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([144, 576, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l6.se.fc1.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l6.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([576, 144, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l6.se.fc2.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([576])
blocks.b4_l6.project.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([144, 576, 1, 1, 1])
blocks.b4_l6.project.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([144])
blocks.b4_l6.project.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([144])
conv7.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([640, 144, 1, 1, 1])
conv7.conv_1.norm.weight : torch.Size([640])
conv7.conv_1.norm.bias : torch.Size([640])
classifier.0.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([2048, 640, 1, 1, 1])
classifier.0.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([2048])
classifier.3.conv_1.conv3d.weight : torch.Size([600, 2048, 1, 1, 1])
classifier.3.conv_1.conv3d.bias : torch.Size([600])

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What is the semantic meaning of the two channels?  If you know the semantic meaning of the two channels, and the semantic meaning of the three channels, you might be able to add a layer that converts (e.g. grayscale -> RGB).  If you don't know or if that's impossible, your two options are probably to train a layer that converts, or to just retrain the pretrained network.

Answer (score 0):

If the layer expects three channels then you cannot do otherwise. You must provide a tensor with three channels.

An alternative would be to replace the first layer with a new [`nn.Conv3d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv3d.html) which has two channels only:

```
model.conv1.conv_1.conv3d = nn.Conv3d(2, 16)
```

Comment: I have done this, but pretrained model is pretrained on 3 channels. Therefore, If i reduce the input channel by 1 then it will be incompatible with the pretrained model which does have weights with 3 channel.

Comment: Of course, if you overwrite your first layer then you discard the pre-trained weights for that first layer. There is not way around this. This first layer should be learned with 
 ease using finetuning on your 2-channel image dataset.

Comment: I have solved it by reducing the 1 dim from 3 channels of pretrained model.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you did exactly, you reduced what?

Comment: The pretrained weights on RGB stream has the three channel, But I wanted to use 2 channels of optical flow stream and train it through the same pretrained model.  I checked the parameter of pretrained model, first layer contains three channel. Therefore I went to the modal and changed the input channels value; 3 to 2, and then I read the parameters pretrained modal. Then wherever it has 3 channels, I reduce it to two channels.  Then they both got compatibility, and solved the issue.

Comment: model1.conv1.conv_1.conv2d.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(model1.conv1.conv_1.conv2d.weight[:,:2])

Comment: If you're not using RGB anymore, it doesn't make much sense to keep only the first two channels on your convolution layer. How could you just reduce to 3 channels? Just out of curiosity: how is the resulting 2-channel element constructed (w.r.t. to the original 3-channel element)?

Comment: I am using optical flow, which computes 2 channels, one on x-axis and one on y-axis. Optical flow used to extract temporal information, I reduced the one dimension from the RGB pretrained model, and it worked fine for me, and giving accuracy better than the modal when I train it from scratch.